# Branching based on user input w/ raw_input(); no path followed

Tags: python, if-statement

I don't understand why my code doesn't work. 
Expected behaviour:

- Read what the user is inputting
- Respond with an appropriate message like *"you have choose to encrypt"*

The code below prompts the user for input, but none of the lines given in the `if` block is run, even if the user enters `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Here's my code:

```
print ("Press 1 to encrypt, 2 to decrypt and 3 to exit")

raw_input()

if raw_input == "1":
    print ("you have choosen to encrypt")
elif raw_input == "2":
    print ("you have choosen to decrypt")
elif raw_input == "3":
    print ("you have choosen to exit, goodbye!")
```

Comment: what language is this? edit your post and add a tag. also, it doesn't look like all the relevant code is here. what's in `raw_input()` / where is that defined?

Comment: Debug! Add print statements such as `raw_input` which seems to be both a function and a variable, does that make sense?

Comment: hint: what is `type(raw_input)`?

Comment: A title of the form "please help me, I don't understand why this doesn't work" is very poor form here -- *every* question is a request for help, and *everybody* asking a question here doesn't understand why their original code didn't work. Making your question title specific enough that it wouldn't apply to every single other question on the site is an important starting point.

Comment: *"My code doesn't work"* doesn't accurately describe your problem. Please specify **what** doesn't work.

Comment: Btw, thanks for clearing up the title @CharlesDuffy, I forgot it in my edit :-)

Comment: NP. For someone just starting out here, editing to show by example how to ask a better question makes sense (though one could also hope for a person to look at other well-regarded questions and learn by example). In any event, let's hope that it sticks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `raw_input()` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) from Python. You should store the user input into a variable before proceeding to the if-else statement. Adding an "else" will be nice.

```
print ("Press 1 to encrypt, 2 to decrypt and 3 to exit")

user_input = raw_input()

if user_input == "1":
    print ("you have choosen to encrypt")
elif user_input == "2":
    print ("you have choosen to decrypt")
elif user_input == "3":
    print ("you have choosen to exit, goodbye!")
else:
    print("Please enter 1, 2, or 3.")
```